# Creating an object from html elements using JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create an object from html elements using JavaScript and jQuery.

The object i want to create is

```
{
  array:[{infraStructureType: 'value', hostId: 'value'}, {infraStructureType: 'value', hostId: 'value'}]
}
```

So my code to create above object is

```
  var obj = {}, dataObj = {compareESX: []};
  $('.checkBox:checked').each(function () {
    obj.infraStructureType = $(event.target).attr('hostId');
    obj.hostId = $(event.target).attr('infrastructureType');
    console.log(obj);
    dataObj.compareESX.push(obj);
    console.log(dataObj);
  });
```

In above code "console.log(obj)" gives correct output but, when i push it in array "dataObj.compareESX" 
Only information of last 'obj' is getting pushed number of times the each loop executes.

Comment: Where do you get `event.target` from? You loop over every checked input, but get attributes from the the same object in every iteration. I think you should use `$(this).attr(...)` instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to put your object definitions `var obj = {}` *inside* your `each` loop. Right now you are using the *same* object for every entry in the loop. Instead, you should create a new object for every checkbox over which you loop.

```
var dataObj = {compareESX: []};
$('.checkBox:checked').each(function () {
  var obj = {};
  obj.infraStructureType = $(event.target).attr('hostId');
  obj.hostId = $(event.target).attr('infrastructureType');
  console.log(obj);
  dataObj.compareESX.push(obj);
  console.log(dataObj);
});
```

Comment: You get three different `dataObj`. Which is not intended output as per questioner.

Comment: If i do so, my object 'obj' will get empty each iteration of a loop. I want my object outside the loop only

Comment: @Pankaj I suppose you only need `dataObj` outside of the loop. It contains an array `compareESX` with the `obj` instances for every checkbox

Answer (score 0):

JS uses Call by reference method.So when update obj it changes all values. You need to do deep copy.Use this

```
dataObj.compareESX.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));
```

Comment: Here is fiddle of my solution view console for result
[http://jsfiddle.net/anqu3zur/](http://jsfiddle.net/anqu3zur/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/np0y6j6h/)
We need to define the obj again to clear the previous values.

```
var dataObj = {compareESX: []};
  $('.checkBox:checked').each(function (e) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.infraStructureType = $(this).attr('hostId');
    obj.hostId = $(this).attr('infrastructureType');
    //console.log(obj);
    dataObj.compareESX.push(obj);
    //console.log(dataObj);
  });
console.log(dataObj);
```